# How to change a td-tag to a input-tag in html when clicking?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a problem in the following HTML-page. I have a html-table where I want that, when the user clicks on one of the td´s on my page, someone can change the content of that td. I think the easiest way of doing this is to change the html-tag. But how can I do that? Or do you know another solution to change content of a td-tag by the user?
I am working also with AngularJS and JQuery, so maybe there is a good solution.

I have the following table-code on pastebin. (stackoverflow didn´t show it correctly) http://pastebin.com/AnjpSbdq

Additional I want that the possibility, to change that content, is disappearing when the user clicks somewhere else on my page. (and maybe also when he presses enter.)

Thanks for all your tips!

Comment: Cant a simple innerTHTML work?
Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example..

Comment: Is there a reason you want to change the tag instead of hiding/showing an input field?

Comment: If you change the `<td>` into an `<input>` you immediately invalidate your HTML and cause issues with your DOM; so I'd strongly suggest that you don't do this. Though, admittedly, this has come up quite a long time after it was asked, and you've taken no time to respond to any of the comments or answers, so I'm guessing you've lost interest anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I think is better that you set an input with type text in tds and initiate it with your own value, and user can change it ... it's like old placeholder

`<input type='text' name='NAME' value='initiate-value'>`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @amin. It's way easier to replace the inner content of the td tag with some input. It should look something like this.

```
var td = document.querySelector('td.clickToEdit');
td.onclick = function() {
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.value = td.textContent;
  td.innerHTML = '';
  td.appendChild(input);
  input.focus();

  //When input looses focus it gets deleted.
  input.onblur = function() {
    td.removeChild(input);
    td.textContent = input.value;
  }
}
```

## Edit:

There's an alternative way of doing it which involves making `contentEditable="true"` all your `td`'s. Content editable is an html property. You can set it like this:

```
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for(var i=0; i<tds.length; i++) {
  tds[i].contentEditable = 'true';
}
```